# Rails 4/RSpec: ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller

I have a simple form.

```
        <%= simple_form_for @user, html: { multipart: true }, remote: true do |f| %>
         <div class = "UserEditsJS">
          <div class="row">
            <div id = "NoPaddingFormShort" class = "col-lg-6  col-lg-offset-0 col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-6">
              <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control-small-short' %>
            </div>
            <div id = "NoPaddingFormShort" class = "col-lg-6  col-md-5  col-sm-6 col-sm-6">
              <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control-small-short' %>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

An an update action

```
        def update
         respond_to do |format|
           if @user.update(user_params)
            if @user.save
            flash.now[:success] = "Profile updated"
            format.html { redirect_to @user }
            format.js { render 'business_card'}
           else
             flash.now[:danger] = "There was a problem with your update"
             format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user) }
             format.js 
          end
         end
        end
```

I am running an spec

```
 it "current user tries to delete their first name" do
     put(:update, :id => @user.id, :user => invalid_attributes)
     @user.reload
     expect(response).to redirect_to(@user), format: 'js'
     expect(@user.first_name).to_not eql invalid_attributes[:first_name]
 end
```

The user model requires a first name.

```
 1) UsersController User updates current user tries to delete their first name
   Failure/Error: put(:update, :id => @user.id, :user => invalid_attributes)
   ActionController::UnknownFormat:
   ActionController::UnknownFormat
   # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:48:in `update'
   # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The issue obviously is with the format

I have tried:

```
   format.js  { render js: 'business_card'}
```

and

```
  format.js  { render 'business_card'}
```

in the controller as well as several other options.

The specs for when a user updates successfully all work, just not when the update fails. There are many examples of this on SO but not seem to address this specific question. I'm sure its a one line answer....I just can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set format in request like this:
`put :update, :id => @user.id, :user => invalid_attributes, format: :js`
or set params hash `params = { id: @user.id, user: invalid_attributes, format: :js }` and call put with this params like this `put :update, params`

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. 
I got the same error, when testing `POST` request with 
`respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end`